# Почему не отображаются фотографии? Какая ошибка в разметке? HTML

Tags: html

```
<!DOCTYPE>   
<html>
    <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
       <title>Водопады</title>
    </head>
    <body background=#2C5E62>               
        <table border="25" width="900px" cellpadding="50" align="center" background="Красивые.jpg" width="1000" height="111">         
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <h1>
                       <font size="7">ПУЗЫРЬКОВАЯ ПАНЕЛЬ</font>
                    </h1>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="50px" align="center">
            <font size="7">.</font>
        </table>
        <table border="25" width="700px" cellpadding="0"  align="center" valign="center"  >
            <tr>
              <th>
                  <img src="panel_0.jpg" alt="пример панели" width="700px"> 
              </th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: В разметке ошибки нет. Видимо фотографии, которую вы указали - нет. Укажите правильный путь и проверьте наличие файла по указанному пути.

Answer (score 2):

При тестировании веб-страницы на локальном компьютере все изображения обычно показываются корректно, однако после публикации на сайте возникает ситуация, что рисунки не видны. Это может происходить по ряду причин, рассмотренных далее.

Несовпадение регистра
В большинстве случаев в качестве операционной системы веб-сервера выступают Unix-подобные системы, которые различают регистр файла. Иными словами, файлы с именами PIC.gif, pic.gif и Pic.gif являются разными. При обращении из HTML-кода эту особенность необходимо учитывать и писать адрес изображения следует именно так, как он записан в системе. Чтобы не возникало путаницы, обычно договариваются, что все имена файлов и папок пишутся в нижнем регистре, также хранятся и документы.

Неверный адрес файла
Ошибка доступа к файлу часто возникает при неверной записи имени файла или папки где он хранится, т.е. из-за обычной опечатки. Также это происходит при неправильном указании относительного адреса файла вида ../../images/file.gif.

Использование локального адреса
Некоторые программы для редактирования HTML-кода добавляют изображения в виде локального адреса, начинающегося на ключевое слово file:///. Далее следует путь к файлу в виде строки c:/имя папки/имя файла. Изображение при этом исправно показывается на локальном компьютере, а на сервере нет, поскольку на нем не существует заданного пути. В подобных случаях достаточно заменить локальный адрес к файлу на относительный.

[Все уже загуглено до нас](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/pochemu-izobrazhenie-ne-pokazyvaetsya-na-sayte)

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, а что не так???
Код - https://jsfiddle.net/8y96umnb/

```html
<table border="25" width="900px" cellpadding="50" align="center" background="Красивые.jpg" width="1000" height="111"> 

<tr>
<th>
<h1>
<font size="7">ПУЗЫРЬКОВАЯ ПАНЕЛЬ</font>
</h1>
</th>
</tr>
      </table>


      <table width="50px" align="center">

      <font size="7">.</font>

      </table>


      <table border="25" width="700px" cellpadding="0"  align="center" valign="center"  >
      <tr>
      <th>

      <img src="http://time-for-rest.com/uploads/images/news/VodopadViktoriya/4.jpg" alt="пример панели" width="700px"> 

      </th>
      </tr>
      </table>
```